# Why isn't data passed to the client after a page has been idle for some time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, webforms

I have a website (ASP.NET webforms), and I use a jQuery plugin to build a tree on the client side. For this I build a string with StringBuilder, and then have my data like this:

```
dataForTree = "var data=" + sb.ToString() + ";";
```

Then I pass this to my tree by using RegisterClientScriptBlock, like this:

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "allData"))
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "allData", dataForTree, true);
}
```

And on my client I receive the data like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#myTree").dynatree({
        children:   $(data)
        });
});
```

Now I know the data is passed correctly, because I get the right treeview on load, and all is great. When I activate a node, I need to display some data about this node, so I make a postback to apply to the server, and I pass the data again. This works as well, everything is displayed great.

But then I leave this page be for a while, just a few minutes is enough, and activate a node again. And then there's the problem. My tree disappears. When I look at the code in Chrome debugger or in Firebug, I see that data variable is not there. Although, I repeat, I pass it to the client on every postback. Why this happens - I never know. Seriously, I've broken my head over it, I just can't see why it is as it is.

Comment: Maybe your server side stops knowing you(r state)

Comment: @AbiusX Hmm..how do I know if it does?

Comment: Why do you wrap data in $(data)? Does it contain DOM elements? Also, it really seems like a session-issue. Could you post some more code like when you build the tree server side and when you register your script?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using un UpdatePanel, remeber to check if Session is expired in the PreInit of the page:

```
     protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
     {
         if (Session["User"]==null )
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
     }
```

Comment: Thanks! Thing is I'm not using UpdatePanel :)